# Get all system information on OS X

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

Is there any class/function which gets me the whole system information object?

With system information object I mean all the data that we can see if we open the System Information app on OS X.

I have found a few classes so far, that gives me some information, but not all.

I fear there is no class which can give me all the information at once since I have not found anything in the documentation yet, but I might have overseen it since I am pretty new to OS X development and not yet familiar with the SDKs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `system_profiler` on `NSTask`

```
let task = NSTask()
let outputPipe = NSPipe()

task.launchPath = "/usr/sbin/system_profiler"
task.arguments = ["-xml", "-detailLevel", "mini"]
task.standardOutput = outputPipe
task.launch()
let outputData = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()

let output = NSString(data: outputData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
print(output)
```

This syntax returns the minimum information as property list.
For further information like other `detailLevel` values see the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, thats what I need. Is this a hacky solution? Or is it common (or reasonable) to run a program as a subprocess?

Comment: It's not hacky. Calling an public executable in the BSD subsystem is a usual procedure. But consider that retrieving the data is synchronous and can take a lot of time so it's recommended to call this process on a background thread.

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks.